# C# Использование библиотеки LinqToExcel

Tags: c#, linq

Необходимо получать и сравнивать два массива данных из Excel. Для этого было принято решение использовать библиотеку LinqToExcel. Проблема заключается в том, что мне необходимо получать данные из отчетов в которых заголовки столбцов записаны с использованием точки.
Например:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создано два класса в которых через атрибут [ExcelColumn("Гос.номер")] настроен maping свойств на столбцы файла Excel.
При загрузке файлов я получаю все значения у которых в названии столбца не используется точка, а там где она присутствует приходит null.
Метод получения данных:

```
public void GetDataExcelFile(string pathExcel)
    {
        var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(pathExcel);
        if (pathExcel == excel1)
        {
            var dataExcel = (from c in excel.Worksheet<TSKAS>()                                 
                             select c).ToList();
        }
        else if (pathExcel == excel2)
        {
            var dataExcel = (from c in excel.Worksheet<TSATX>()                                 
                             select c).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Пример одного из классов:

```
internal class TSKAS
{
    [ExcelColumn("Тип ТС")]
    public string TipTS { get; set; }

    [ExcelColumn("Подтип ТС")]
    public string PodTipTS { get; set; }

    [ExcelColumn("Марка ТС")]
    public string MarkaTS { get; set; }

    [ExcelColumn("Вид ТС")]
    public string VidTSK { get; set; }

    [ExcelColumn("Гос.номер")]
    public string GosNum { get; set; }
}
```

Не знаю в чем проблема, но видимо точка в названии столбца каким-то образом влияет на определение столбца. Может кто-то решал такую проблему?

Comment: переименовать столбец?

Comment: в квадратные скобки пробовали заключать? [ExcelColumn("[Гос.номер]")]

Comment: переименовать столбец? Не вариант, это будет делать user, так что бегать и объяснять что удалите точки не комельфо, все должно работать без танцев с бубном.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить точку на решётку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548176/linqtoexcel-dot-in-header

Comment: Спасибо @timur так работает супер: Попробуйте заменить точку на решётку stackoverflow.com/questions/19548176/linqtoexcel-dot-in-header